# call method using onclick event in invokeelementmethod() and insertadjacentHTML()

Tags: angular, typescript, onclick

I'm trying to call **getInput()** method in **save** button via onclick event. But this generates following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.getInput is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):1)
```

I want to call getInput() method. I also tried to call **getInput()** without **this**. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.inputYT.nativeElement, "insertAdjacentHTML", ["beforeend", "<button onclick = 'this.getInput()' type = 'button' class = 'btn btn-success' style = 'position: relative; top: -50px; right: 6px; float: right' >Save</button>"]);
```

full code:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, ElementRef, ViewChild, Renderer } from "angular2/core";
import {Video} from "./video";

@Component(
{
selector: "playlist",
templateUrl: "app/ts/playlist.component.html",
inputs: ["videos"]
})
export class Playlist
{
iframe: HTMLIFrameElement;
div: HTMLDivElement = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
input: HTMLInputElement;
videoCode: string[];
@ViewChild("inputDiv") inputYT: ElementRef;
constructor(private renderer: Renderer)
{
}
getInput()
{
    this.videoCode = this.input.value.split("=", 2);
    this.videoCode = this.input.value.split("&", 2);
}
addVideos()
{
    if(this.input)
        return;
    this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.inputYT.nativeElement, "insertAdjacentHTML", ["beforebegin", "<script src = 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>"]);
    this.input = document.createElement("input");
    this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.inputYT.nativeElement, "insertAdjacentHTML", ["beforeend", "<input type = 'text' class = 'form-control input-lg' id = 'inputText' style = 'margin: 10px 0px; width: 100%;' placeholder = 'Paste youtube video link here'/>"]);
    this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.inputYT.nativeElement, "insertAdjacentHTML", ["beforeend", "<button onclick = 'this.getInput()' type = 'button' class = 'btn btn-success' style = 'position: relative; top: -50px; right: 6px; float: right'>Save</button>"]);
}
onSelect(vid: Video)
{
    if(this.iframe)
        this.div.removeChild(this.iframe);
    this.iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    this.iframe.setAttribute("width", "800");
    this.iframe.setAttribute("height", "500");
    this.iframe.setAttribute("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + vid.link);
    this.div.appendChild(this.iframe);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add onclick event like this -

`(click)="getInput ()"`